# Get file synchronisation status in Win10 via VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint, windows-10, onedrive

Is there a method in VBA to find the file synchronisation status?

I am referring to a situation when I create or modify a large file, which takes a while to synchronise via OneDrive to the cloud (my OneDrive or Sharepoint), and then I want to run some procedures that are contigent on it being synced, but I have no idea how to get that information. I found just an Application.Sync object, which is deprecated and it seems to have no relation to OneDrive.

Comment: I have the same question the Application.Sync object is broken (it reports incorrect values on it's properties) this is likely due to it being deprecated, but what object should I use?